# pandas: remove rows with 'tmp' in them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row

I have a pandas dataframe in Python, the dataframe looks like this:

```
    id   count   table_size  table_name
     1    835        0.52    some_table
     2    543        1.02    another_table
     3    727        0.85    tmp_test_table
     4    834        1.46    empty_table
     5    552        0.99    tmp_my_table
```

I wish to run a command to remove completly all the rows with `table_name` that starts with "tmp", so for my example, the result would be:

```
    id   count   table_size  table_name
     1    835        0.52    some_table
     2    543        1.02    another_table
     5    552        0.99    tmp_my_table
```

I do not care about the id being messed up.

Comment: None of the table_name have “temp” in them. Do you mean “tmp”?

Comment: Your results table also contains a row with “tmp” in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use str.startswith to filter out

```
df[~df.table_name.str.startswith('tmp')]

   id  count  table_size     table_name
0   1    835        0.52     some_table
1   2    543        1.02  another_table
3   4    834        1.46    empty_table
```